# return std::move a class with a unique_ptr member

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, stdmove

Why can't I return a class containing a `std::unique_ptr`, using `std::move` semantics (I thought), as in the example below? I thought that the return would invoke the move ctor of class `A`, which would `std::move` the `std::unique_ptr`. (I'm using GCC 11.2, C++20)

Example:

```
#include <memory>

class A {
  public:
    explicit A(std::unique_ptr<int> m): m_(std::move(m)) {}
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> m_;
};

A makit(int num) {
    auto m = std::make_unique<int>(num);
    return std::move(A(m));  // error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]'x86-64 gcc 11.2 #1
}

int main() {
    auto a = makit(42);
    return 0;
}
```

I believe the solution is to return a `std::unique_ptr`, but before I give in I wonder why the `std::move` approach doesn't work.

Comment: This isn't about moving the `A`, it's about moving `m`, which you don't do.

Comment: Your constructor is taking the parameter by value, which you can't do with `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Yes, you can.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica really?  How does it retain its uniqueness then?

Comment: @MarkRansom - `std::move(m)`, now the parameter is initialized from an rvalue and is the sole owner.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica my point was that by the time you've reached the `std::move` in this code you've already attempted a copy.

Comment: @MarkRansom - No you haven't. You need to move the `m` in `makit`, and that will initialize the parameter.

Comment: @StoryTeller ah you're correct, changing it to `return std::move(A(std::move(m)));` works. Thanks!

Comment: @voxoid: `return A(std::move(m));` should be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought that the return would invoke the move ctor of class A, which would `std::move` the `std::unique_ptr`.

All true, but the move constructor only moves the members of `A`. It cannot move unrelated satellite unique pointers for you.

In the expression `A(m)`, you use `m` as an lvalue. That will try to copy `m` in order to initialize the parameter `m` of `A::A` (btw, terrible naming scheme for reasoning about all of this). If you move *that*, i.e. `A(std::move(m))`, the expression becomes well-formed.

And on that subject, the outer `std::move` in `std::move(A(...))` is redundant. `A(...)` is already an rvalue of type `A`. The extra `std::move` does nothing good here.